# Is Toyosato Elementary School open to visitors?

Tags: k-on, tourism

K-On! was based on a real-world elementary school in Toyosato. According to [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toyosato,_Shiga) on Wikipedia, the elementary school moved to a new building in 2004.

Is the old elementary school open year-round to visitors and anime fans?

Comment: https://punynari.wordpress.com/2010/09/25/k-on-school-anime-pilgrimage-part-1/

Comment: (This question is being discussed on meta: http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/q/2461/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's open to public.
The other room of the building is using as office of city.

Some small things if you want to visit.

- You need to check schedule, for example 3/1 to 3/18, it was [closed](http://toyosato-kanko.jp/news/%E8%B1%8A%E9%83%B7%E5%B0%8F%E5%AD%A6%E6%A0%A1%E6%97%A7%E6%A0%A1%E8%88%8E%E7%BE%A4%E3%81%AE%E3%81%94%E8%A6%8B%E5%AD%A6%E5%88%B6%E9%99%90%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6/).
- [8:30 to 17:00 on weekday. 9:00 to 17:30 on weekend](http://bushitsu.blog47.fc2.com/blog-entry-22.html).
- It's free but need to sign-in.
- Some people brake the building the city [considering to close](http://www.town.toyosato.shiga.jp/contents_detail.php?co=tpc&frmId=438). be a good otaku.